# Use of List of ints in EF query - Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

Using Entity Framework Core 3.1 I have the following query:

```
    var ids = new List<Int32> { 1, 2, 3 }; 

    users = context.Users

      .Where(x => ids.All(y => x.UserSkills.Any(z => y == z.SkillId)));

    var result = await users.ToListAsync();
```

When I run this query I get the following error:

```
'The LINQ expression 'DbSet<User>
    .Where(u => True && __ids_0
        .All(y => DbSet<UserSkill>
            .Where(u0 => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(u, "Id") != null && EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(u, "Id") == EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(u0, "UserId"))
            .Any(u0 => y == u0.SkillId)))' could not be translated. 
    Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()
```

How can I solve this?